# Upper and lower bounds - nearest 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am really confused about rounding number to the nearest 5, i was practicing bounds gcse questions and I had a question saying that 135 was rounded to nearest 5m, find the upper and lower bounds. I thought it was going to be 136.5 until my friend told me it was 137.5, I got really confused. Can someone explain how this works? Is there a way a value that nearest 5 is x or something like that? An clear explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Where would you like $137.0$ to round to, if you're aiming for the nearest multiple of $5$?

Comment: It might sound stupid to you but if i was doing i would round it to 138.5

Comment: Is $138.5$ a multiple of $5$? (It's not: Multiples of 5 look like 0, 5, 10, 15, ...)

Comment: How is 137 a multiple of 5 then?

Comment: It's not, which is why you need to round it, either to 135 or 140. 135 is closer. The point of this is that 136.5 is not a cutoff for the things that round to 135.

Comment: So how it would it work then? Does rounding to nearest 5 have like a specific value that it would be easy to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

The cutoff is half way between two neighboring numbers you can round to.  When rounding to the nearest $5$ you could round to $135$ or to $140$.  The point half way between is $\frac 12(135+140)=137.5$  Any number less than $137.5$ (and greater than $132.5$) should be rounded to $135$.  This is general.  The interval between cutoff points is the size of your increment of rounding, half above a target and half below.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I learnt when doing bounds is you can half the number it's been rounded to and use that to find the upper and lower bounds.
 Eg. 135 rounded to the nearest 5
Half 5 to get 2.5 
The upper bound is 135 + 2.5=137.5
The lower bound is 135-2.5=132.5

Comment: A correct answer is at the heart of this solution, but I think it's not very clear. The two (semi-automated) comments you received above this are from people reacting negatively to your answer in certain review queues. I think if you flesh out your answer, it might better address the question and attract a more positive reaction. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By halving 5 (the number you are rounding to) = 2.5
Then to find the upper bound you add it to the number you are rounding so 135 + 2.5 = 137.5 ( this is a multiple of 5).
To get the lower bound you do the opposite so 135 - 2.5 = 132.5 ( which is also a multiple of 5).
UB= 137.5
LB= 132.5

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).